# How do I keep grunt server running even if there is a coffeescript compile error?

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

Some time, I will have a typo in my coffee file which breaks the compiler which then shuts down the grunt server with a "failed to compile" error message.

How do I prevent the server from exiting and keep watching until the next successful compile?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--force` option when running grunt to prevent it from exiting when a task has an error.  For example:

`grunt coffee --force`

Comment: Doesn't work. I use `grunt --watch --force` and it will dump the process if coffee fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have node-supervisor running on my output directory without any interactiom with the grunt scripts. My Coffee Script compilation task will error out (giving me a warning) but it won't stop my server at all. Then you can fix the error, save and wait for the server to restart.

If you have the screen real estate to allow for it, I'd recommend this setup since it won't potentially hide errors but will still allow you to test if the errors are unrelated to the task your working on.